# Trying to build an Age Calculator

Tags: android, calculator

If I'm given a **Date of Birth (d.o.b.)** then how we ***Calculate current Age*** in android:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        textView_cage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_cage);
        textView_currentagediff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_currentagediff);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            System.out.println("Current Setdate");
            System.out.println("Year" + year);
            System.out.println("Month" + month);
            System.out.println("Date" + day);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            mDateDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
            Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
            System.out.println("Current Setdate");

            Date d1 = new Date();
            int year2 = d1.getYear();
            int month2 = d1.getMonth();
            int day2 = d1.getDate();

            System.out.println("Current aaj ki date");
            System.out.println("Year" + year2);
            System.out.println("Month" + month2);
            System.out.println("Date" + day2);

            int year3 = year2 - year;
            int month3 = (month2 + 1) - month;
            int day3 = day2 - day;
            System.out.println("Current aaj kitnhesal k ho gaye ");
            System.out.println("Year" + year3);
            System.out.println("Month" + month3);
            System.out.println("Date" + day3);
            setnewage(year3, month3, day3);

        }

        private void setnewage(int year4, int month4, int day4) {
            Date d5 = new Date(year4, month4, day4);

            CharSequence day = DateFormat.format("d", d5);
            CharSequence month = DateFormat.format("M", d5);
            CharSequence year = DateFormat.format("yyyy", d5);

            textView_currentagediff.setText(year + " Years " + month + " Months and " + day + " days");
            Date d1 = new Date();
            int year2 = d1.getYear();
            int month2 = d1.getMonth();
            int day2 = d1.getDate();


    }

    }

}
```

I want to select the date of birth by `Datepickerdialog` and after selection of the date, I want to get Current Age. 
Please give me some example in Android.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
// get the current date in format specified.
    public String getCurrentDate(){

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm aa");
    return  df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}

public void getDateDifference(String dob){

            String dateOfBirth = dob;
        String dateCurrent = getCurrentDate();

        //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;

        try {
            d1 = format.parse(dateOfBirth);
            d2 = format.parse(dateCurrent);

            //in milliseconds
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);               

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**Step 1 :** Get the date of birth entered using `DatePickerDialog` . Call the method `getDateDifference` and pass this value of dob as argument.

**Step 2 :** set the difference obtained to the text view using `setText()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple java code you have to supply your birth date and current date, then your final result will be your age.

```
public static int getDiffBetYears(Date first, Date last) {
    Calendar firstDate = getCalendar(first);
    Calendar secDate = getCalendar(last);
    int diff = secDate.get(YEAR) - firstDate.get(YEAR);
    if (firstDate.get(MONTH) > secDate.get(MONTH) || 
        (firstDate.get(MONTH) == secDate.get(MONTH) && a.get(DATE) > secDate.get(DATE))) {
        diff--;
    }
    return diff;
}

public static Calendar getCalendar(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
}
```

Comment: hello i want read Birth date on Edit Text option and after read birth date and calculte diffrence between current age and birthdate how we will provide reslut another text view ,,

Comment: Ok..
Then what you have to do is...Extract date,month and year from `text` you get from `edittext` and then have look at these [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2687094/1758960)