# Create first day of month from YearChooser and MonthChooser of JCalendar

Tags: java, date, constructor

I have YearChooser named yc, MonthChooser mc. I want to get values from them and create the first day of that month.
Ex: If year is 2015, month is 9, I will get the day 01/09/2015

The code:

```
Date d = new Date (year, month, 1);
```

is deprecated, and the result given wrong year (year 3125!)
How can I get my date?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687081/what-is-the-accepted-way-to-replace-java-util-dateyear-month-day. Just remember that the first month is numbered as 0.

Comment: @verdana Is 2-15 a typo? Did you mean 2015?

Comment: Yes, 2015 :) I fixed it @BasilBourque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the doc

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year +
> 1900, month, date) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date).
>
> Parameters:
> year - the year minus 1900.
>
> month - the month between 0-11.
>
> date - the day of the month between 1-31.

So for year 2015 you should pass 115 as year in the `Date` constructor